# how to use resolve(url) to redirect homepage in Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, http-redirect

I saw this example in [Django documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse)

> One possible use of resolve() would be to test 
>       whether a view would raise a Http404 error before redirecting to it:

`app/views.py:`

```
from urlparse import urlparse
from django.core.urlresolvers import resolve
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404

def myview(request):
    next = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER', None) or '/'
    response = HttpResponseRedirect(next)

    # modify the request and response as required, e.g. change locale
    # and set corresponding locale cookie

    view, args, kwargs = resolve(urlparse(next)[2])
    kwargs['request'] = request
    try:
        view(*args, **kwargs)
    except Http404:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    return response
```

How to use this is my question?
Consider this scenario:

```
Invalid URL -- http://example.com/givemesomething 
   Valid URL -- http://example.com/giveone
```

my `urlConf` will be

```
urlpatterns=("",
             url(r'^$', 'blog.index'),
             url(r'^giveone/$', 'blog.getone'),
             #redirect everything else to blog.index
                 )
```

I have to make all requests that I get to go `views.myview` (above), validate and then redirect. what would would be the `urlpattern` for that?

Comment: *Why* do you have to make all the requests go via that view? Why not deal with 404s in the usual way?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I can't think of a situation where you need to "override" the real http status code. If a page is not found, it should return a 404 status code.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: that is the requirement. To redirect any invalid requests on the domain to home page. or some  other page instead of throwing 404Error. for example try this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/@134" it does not exist. but it redirects to tell something. I want to achieve the same. for this, I have to check if a URL that is passed is a valid request or not?

Comment: No, you don't. You write a [404 handler view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/views/#http-not-found-view), and do what you need to there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the suggestion. That is a brilliant idea. just for conceptual purposes, is it in fact possible to achieve the same using the above `myview`. I am concerned that will result in endless loop. If not, I would like to see how it can be done. This is just for academic purposes.